# How to write an integer in binary in C

Tags: c, binary

I know that C uses `"%x"` for hexadecimal and `"%d"` for decimal and I already tried using `"%b"`.

How can I write an integer in binary in C?

Comment: You must do it yourself, there is no specifier for binary.

Comment: Already a answer is there in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111928/is-there-a-printf-converter-to-print-in-binary-format

Comment: What's stopping you from writing code that does that?